# In WPF how can I create a KeyGesture that only binds to the numpad ENTER key?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a KeyGesture binding in code, something like this:

```
KeyGestureConverter converter = new KeyGestureConverter();
KeyGesture gesture = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(shortcutText) as KeyGesture;
if (gesture == null)
    // error
KeyBinding keyBinding = new KeyBinding(command, gesture);
control.InputBindings.Add(keyBinding);
```

Is there a value for shortcutText that will result in a KeyGesture for the numpad ENTER key only?
I've found values for all numpad keys, except enter.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to differentiate between the standard Enter and numpad Enter by just evaluating the string shortcutText. I did a test to see the difference between Key.Return and Key.Enter by the both evaluate to the same string "Enter".

Comment: Sorry, but it is not possible, since both key press returns "Enter" only. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059177/distinguish-between-normal-enter-and-the-number-pad-enter-keypress