# Trigger numpad (right) enter click KeyEvent

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm doing an automation to an old terminal application. For confirm login is needed enter - not normal, but right enter - numpad enter.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

I found ([in Coderanch](https://coderanch.com/t/552392/java/java/Java-Robot-press-keypad-enter)), that in Java it's not possible, but four years ago... Is there any option to do this now? I'm using OpenText HostExplorer terminal, so I'll try dig in settings...

Comment: This question might be useful, I've never actually thought about trying to differentiate which enter key was pressed.  Maybe there's a way to set the extended keypress property?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059177/distinguish-between-normal-enter-and-the-number-pad-enter-keypress

Answer (score 0):

Just go in HostExplorer:

```
Options -> Keyboard Mapping
```

on image you can see, that right CTRL is doing ENTER key.

So click on main ENTER, in Function group choose Action Keys, choose Enter and save your updated mapping... OMFG!